# Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'void (*)(void*)' in MinGW 7.3.0 32bit

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, mingw

I have to integrate the plain C .h file to my C++ project (Qt GUI). For that I have to avoid some function pointers with tricky substitutions. Piece of code you could see below had compiled without any problems in MinGW 5.3.0 C++ before. But when I tried to use more fresh compiler (7.3.0 for C++) I got an error "Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'void (*)(void*)'" but it's still compiling without problem with the same 7.3.0 for C.

```
void func_to_avoid( void* );
void func_to_avoid2( void* );

#ifdef MY_PART
  #define SOME_MACROS( func )       0
  #define SOME_MACROS2( func )      0

#endif

typedef struct
{
#ifdef MY_PART
    void            (*func)(void*);
#else
    AvoidedFunction_t  func;
#endif
}type_descr_t;


const type_descr_t types[]
={
//...
{   
 // SOME_MACROS( func_to_avoid )   // this expression compiles without any problem
    SOME_MACROS( func_to_avoid ) + SOME_MACROS2( func_to_avoid2 )  // **compilation error!**
}
//...
};
```

**Question:
The compiler gives me the error for macro expressions with "+". How to fix it?**

I think it's a matter of casting but I'm not able to solve it by myself. Sure, I always could return to previous compiler version or use another compiler (for example, msvc) but it doesn't look like a solution at all.
**Is there any casting solution to resolve this compilation problem?**

UPDATE: the code below allows to reproduce the error. As I've said it's working with C compiler and with 5.3.0 MinGW C++.

main.c

```
void func_to_avoid( void* );
void func_to_avoid2( void* );

#define MY_PART
#ifdef MY_PART
#define SOME_MACROS( func )     0
#define SOME_MACROS2( func )    0

#endif

typedef struct
{
#ifdef MY_PART
    void            (*func)(void*);
#else
    AvoidedFunction_t  func;
#endif
}type_descr_t;


const type_descr_t types[]
={
{
    SOME_MACROS( func_to_avoid )+SOME_MACROS2( func_to_avoid2 )
}};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. Is `MY_PART` defined? What if it is not defined? Then `SOME_MACROS` will cause an error like here: https://godbolt.org/z/Mse9n8

Comment: i dont understand it completely, but your issue boils down to `int* x = 0;` vs `int* x = 0+0;`, the latter is rejected with same error. Why do you want to add function pointers in the first place?

Comment: If you use GCC or Clang, try to enable the `-E` flag to see how the macros are expanding.

Comment: You can't add `void` function pointers together, change their type to something else.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that `+` construct? Shouldn't it be `{SOME_MACROS( func_to_avoid )}, {SOME_MACROS2( func_to_avoid2 )}`?

Comment: Wouldn't "mocking" undesired functions be the smarter way to solve this? That is: `void dummy_scanf (const char*s,...){}` then `#define scanf dummy_scanf`. This should compile to a no-op.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Actually, I've done it! Your comments forced me to think harder and I found out how to make this 'mocking' trick. I have this code compiled now without any warnings. For what purpose does it serve? What I need it's extracting values of some fields from const struct types[]. I'm sure there're another solutions for that task but this one suits me very well.

```
void func_to_avoid( void* );
void func_to_avoid2( void* );

#define MY_PART
#ifdef MY_PART
#define SOME_MACROS( func )     0
#define SOME_MACROS2( func )    0

#endif

typedef struct
{
   char* info_example1; // for clarification
#ifdef MY_PART
    //void          (*func)(void*);
    int func;
#else
    AvoidedFunction_t  func;
#endif
}type_descr_t;


const type_descr_t types[]
={
{
    "info_ex1",
    //I don't need this variable and now I can just skip it
    SOME_MACROS( func_to_avoid )+SOME_MACROS2( func_to_avoid2 ) 
}};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As this is C++ (it is different in C), your problem boils down to

```
int* x = 0;
```

vs

```
int* x = 0+0;
```

The latter does not compile. Gccs error message is more or less the same as yours and clangs is a little more helpful:

```
<source>:35:11: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an rvalue of type 'int'
    int* x = 0+0;
          ^   ~~~
```

You can't do it. I cannot recommend you what to do instead, because its not quite clear what the purpose of adding two function pointers (in the case of `MY_PART` is not defined) should be.

Comment: Hmm how did you get that message from clang? `int* x = 0+0;` is compliant C. clang version 11 correctly says "warning: expression which evaluates to zero treated as a null pointer constant of type 'int *' [-Wnon-literal-null-conversion]"

Comment: @Lundin oh sorry. I simply assumed it is C++ without clarifiying that first.

Comment: Oh right, another mis-tagging fiasco. Or well, the OP is using C code in C++ so it's actually valid use of both tags.

Comment: @Lundin actually OP states that it is a C header compiled as C++. I'd still argue that the C tag could/should be removed (but there are really worse cases of such mistagging)

Comment: The current policy is that it's fine to use both tags when porting code between the two languages. In this case C and C++ treat null pointers differently, which isn't an obvious bug to spot.

Comment: @Lundin I read the question again and can only agree. Both tags should be here. Unfortunately misuse is so common that sometimes it triggers the mis-tagging fiasco panic too fast ;)